# Table designing in while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, html-table

I want to show 4 images from database in a table (2*2) I know how to do that. But I have also special condition (if there are less picture than 4, it will show default pictures to show 4 images totally)

I manage this in a while loop. If there are 4 images there is no problem, it works as I want but when there are fewer images (which means default images will be completed 4 images in total) it doesn't work. I can't figure out how to do that.

Any help?

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php                               
$todisplay = 4;

$query = mysql_query("select * from Images where Country_ID=$co_id LIMIT 0,4;");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$x++;
 echo "<td><img src='".$row['I1_Th'] .  "'/></td>";
 $displayed_number++;
 if ($x % 2==0) {
 echo "</tr><tr>";}
}   

echo str_repeat("<td>
<img src='images/png/defthumb.png'> </td>", $todisplay-$displayed_number);
?>
</tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping over the rows returned by your query, why not just loop four times and attempt to fetch a row instead?

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php                               
$tablerows = 2;

$query = mysql_query("select * from Images where Country_ID=$co_id LIMIT " + ($tablerows * 2) + ";");

for ($x = 1; $x <= ($tablerows * 2); $x++) {
  if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<td><img src='".$row['I1_Th'] .  "'/></td>";
  } else {
    echo "<td><img src='images/png/defthumb.png'></td>";
  }
  if ($x % 2==0 && $x != $tablerows * 2) {
    echo "</tr><tr>";}
}
?>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: You may want to use a variable to determine the number of rows (and not the number of images to display) to ensure that you will always have two columns for each row, e.g., my update above.

Answer (score 2):

You were not far from it - simply create another loop that does the same thing, but with the default image instead. Also, the `$displayed_number` seems to hold the same value as `$x`, so I deleted it.

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php                               
$todisplay = 4;

$query = mysql_query("select * from Images where Country_ID=$co_id LIMIT 0,4;");
$x = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$x++;
 echo "<td><img src='".$row['I1_Th'] .  "'/></td>";

 if ($x % 2==0) {
 echo "</tr><tr>";}
}   

while ( $x < $todisplay) {
$x++;
 echo "<td><img src='images/png/defthumb.png'/></td>";
 if ($x % 2==0) {
 echo "</tr><tr>";}
}   
?>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: Dear Tudor, this code makes 2*2 table but default pictures again shows below row for 4 times.